# DataMapper: dm-timestamps doesn't play nice with dm-validations?

Tags: ruby, validation, datamapper

It seems that validations in DataMapper run before dm-timestamps has a chance to autoset the created_at and updated_at fields.

Consider the following:

```
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'dm-timestamps'
require 'dm-validations'

class MyResource
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :mykey, Serial, :key=>true
  property :created_at, DateTime, :required=>true
  property :updated_at, DateTime
end

resource = MyResource.new
resource.save #fails
```

The save fails because created_at is blank.
Interestingly, if you just comment out the "require dm-validations", the problem goes away.
Of course, you can also just remove ":required=>true" from :created_at but that's not what I'm after - created_at is required.  It's just that I'm using dm-timestamps to automatically set it for me.

Anyone else seen this?  Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the `created_at` timestamp is set after validations are run. That's actually a pretty sensible behavior since it won't, in fact, be created if it fails validation. You can either remove the `:required => true` since it's not actually buying you anything or you can set up a `before_validation` hook that sets the timestamp. The second option may have unintended consequences. I don't think so, but I don't know DataMapper well enough to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Under what circumstances would you reasonably expect `created_at` to be NULL?  Are you just defending against manual manipulation of the records in the database?

If that's the case, I'd probably omit the `:required=>true` bit and just enforce that constraint in the database.  Let `dm-timestamps` do it's thing.  It's pretty solid.  That seems like a pragmatic solution.  As they say, "Do the simplest thing that could possibly work."